# Save the results of every iteration into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I use a for loop to iterate in the items from a list.

I would like to keep the whole data from the iteration process into a dataframe

What I tried until know is this:

```
import pandas as pd 
lst = [13,60]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key="xxxxx")
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    SITE.max_pages=10000000
    SITE.page_size=100
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids= df[i])
```

How can I make?

Error:

> endpoint = endpoint.replace("{"+k+"}",
>   ';'.join(requests.compat.quote_plus(str(x)) for x in value))

Answer (score -1):

You can save the data in lists for each column and append to the lists in the for loop. Then after the for loop you can create a new DataFrame and pass a dictionary of the column names and keys and the lists of column data as values to the constructor.